# Running Apache OpenMeetings with Nginx Reverse Proxy?

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, openmeetings

I am trying to install [Apache OpenMeetings](https://openmeetings.apache.org). I however wants to use Nginx as the reverse proxy to run the application on port 443 using Let's Encrypt free SSL.

If I try to load the application on port 5080, I successfully get the interface, but when try using the domain name on port 443 HTTPS, It is not loading the resources.

[Image with Errors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijVQL.png)

Here's my nginx virtual host file.

```
upstream openmeetings {
server 127.0.0.1:5080;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name openmeetings.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name openmeetings.example.com;

    ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/openmeetings.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/openmeetings.example.com/privkey.pem;

    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/openmeetings.access.log;

location / {
        proxy_pass http://openmeetings;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Did you write literally `proxy_pass http://openmeetings;` or are you just trying to hide your local domain name?

Comment: I just want to run this application on `https://openmeetings.mydomain.com`instead of `http://openmeetings.mydomain.com:5080`. , I was just trying this configuration but it does not work. Some websocket problem I guess. If you can help with the Nginx configuration, I will be thankful.

Comment: what openmeetings version is it? 5?

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem. (vit Openmeetings 5.0.0-M4)
I found next:

### Openmeetings use ajax over WebSocket.

adding

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}
```

to http section

and

```
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
```

to location

It solve status 400 problem

### Then I meet problem with Content Security Policy

I feel like connect-src policy configured automatic on first connect to server.
So after change used domain I need restart Openmeetings.

### Problem with media stream play

On Check setup recording produce long browser console message ending with

> onaddstream is deprecated! Use peerConnection.ontrack instead.
>
> ...
>
> Remote ICE candidate received

Look like it incompatibility with old Firefox 54.0 on Linux

On latest Firefox 75.0 on Windows it works!

Answer (score 0):

It is also necessary to rewrite server.xml referring to

[nginx managed SSL with Tomcat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19916906/nginx-managed-ssl-with-tomcat-7)

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve"
           remoteIpHeader="x-forwarded-for"
           remoteIpProxiesHeader="x-forwarded-by"
           protocolHeader="x-forwarded-proto"
    />
```